# Combining the Factory Method and Singleton Design Patterns

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, factory-pattern

I am currently implementing a game in which there are different types of maps. Being all maps, they naturally share certain attributes and methods, so an abstract class `Map` was created, to then be subclassed by maps such as `SafeMap`, `HazardousMap`, `WeirdMap`, etc.

To make it easy to add more maps in the future, the factory method design pattern was used. So the program contains a `MapCreator` class whose code looks something like this:

```java
public class MapCreator{
    public Map createMap(char mapType){
        switch(mapType){
            case 'S':
                return new SafeMap();
            case 'H':
                return new HazardousMap();
            case 'W':
                return new WeirdMap();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would also like to enforce that only one Map instance exists (regardless of the subclass chosen). I've read that the best way to go about this is to deploy the singleton design pattern, where a static instance is declared privately within the class and the constructor is also made private. But I do not know how this can be done in conjunction with the factory method design pattern, since we have multiple subclasses and `getInstance()` has to be in a concrete class.

I appreciate any assistance.

---

Note: I have had a look at [a few similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818199/singleton-in-conjunction-with-the-factory-pattern-in-php5) but I don't think the responses to those are relevant to my case.

Comment: Can you replace a map type once one type is created?  If the player is looking at a "SafeMap" can that be replaced with an instance of say "HazardMap" at some point?

Comment: @markspace No, once the player chooses, the map is fixed throughout the game.

Comment: Then the easiest way to do this is to use a single static field, and return that value if a map is already created.

Comment: @markspace Can you elaborate in an answer perhaps? I'm not sure I get what you mean.

Comment: I would use the [**Multiton pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a single static field, and return that value if a map is already created.

Code is untested, but I think the concept is simple enough:

```
public class MapCreator{
    private static Map theOnlyMap;
    public synchronized Map createMap(char mapType){
        if( theOnlyMap != null ) return theOnlyMap;
        switch(mapType){
            case 'S':
                theOnlyMap = new SafeMap();
                 break;
            case 'H':
                theOnlyMap =  new HazardousMap();
                break;
            case 'W':
                theOnlyMap = new WeirdMap();
                break;
        }
        return theOnlyMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: first time createMap method will return one of these 3 maps, but for the rest of the cases "theOnlyMap" will never null so we can't change the other maps

Comment: Note the comment above by Luke: "No, once the player chooses, the map is fixed throughout the game." @M.ArslanKhan

Answer (score 2):

A ServiceLocator pattern is what you are looking for.

Generally speaking, in order to avoid having to use Singletons everywhere, you tend to use this pattern which can then be mocked for unit tests if necessary.

It consists of a Map which has got the interface class as the key and the object as value (it can hold many Singleton classes/interfaces).

So, you could have a ServiceLocator with a hashmap having an entry with Map.class as key and the desired instance as value.

You would get the value by (for example):

```
ServiceLocator.get(Map.class);
```

Where get is a generic getter that wraps yourHashMap.get(Map.class);

Comment: I didn't use this design pattern because I don't think it's what is expected for my assignment (we didn't cover the ServiceLocator design pattern in class). But thanks for your answer, it sounds like it would work.